# Discord.js - Condition in an awaitMessages

Tags: discord.js

I am creating an awaitMessages for my discord bot to add an item to my virtual shop on my bot. In this awaitMessages I would like to indicate the price of the article. So the answer must be a number, but the problem is that when I write an answer which isn't a number, the awaitMessages is canceled. I would like, when I send a message that isn't a number, it sends an error message but the awaitMessages doesn't cancel and I write a response again.

```
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;

message.channel.send('Price').then(msg => {
                message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { 
                    max: 1, 
                    time: 10000, 
                    errors: ['time'] })

                    .then(collected => {

                     if(isNaN(collected)) return message.channel.send('not a number')})

                    .catch(collected => msg.delete());
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add conditions to your filter.

```js
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id && !isNaN(parseInt(m.content));

message.channel.send('Enter a price\nHas to be a number.').then(msg => {
  message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    max: 1,
    time: 10000,
    errors: ['time']
  })

    .then(collected => {
      // Do something
    })
    .catch(collected => msg.delete());
});
```

This won't send an error message, however it won't trigger your collector and therefore won't stop trying to collect a number until one is sent or until the time runs out.

Comment: Thank you very much !! But it's possible to send an error message ?

Comment: I mentioned this in the answer, you wouldn't be able to send an error message.